# How To Reduce Sensitivity of a Microphone Using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, microphone, data-preprocessing

I am building an android application using Flutter in which the sound is recorded using an external microphone connected to a smart phone. The sound which is received is amplified and I am unable to reduce the sensitivity of the microphone.

Is there a method to reduce the sensitivity of the microphone using flutter. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which API do you use to access the microphone? Any special package or library?

Comment: in order to get input from microphone as 8-bit PCM Stream I have used **"mic_stream"** Flutter package. @jraufeisen